# Break out of for loop

Tags: java

I tried to run the following code but it does not break out of the for loop when the radio button trueButton or falseButton is selected.

```
for(;;){            
    if (trueButton.isSelected() || falseButton.isSelected()){
        System.out.print("Selected");
        break;
    }
}
```

However, if I add System.out.println(""); before the if statement, I am able to break out of the for loop when the trueButton or falseButton is selected.

```
for(;;){
    System.out.println("");
    if (trueButton.isSelected() || falseButton.isSelected()){
        System.out.print("Selected");
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can break out of the loop without adding System.out.println("") before the if statement?

It would be great if someone can explain why the first code does not work too.

As I am new to programming, do forgive me if I am ignorant about anything.

EDIT: I have created a similar scenario below for you all to test out too.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Hello");
    JRadioButton trueButton = new JRadioButton("True ");
    JRadioButton falseButton = new JRadioButton("False ");      

    window.setSize(400, 325);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    window.add(trueButton);
    window.add(falseButton);

    trueButton.setVisible(true);
    falseButton.setVisible(true);
    window.setVisible(true);

    for(;;){
        if (trueButton.isSelected() || falseButton.isSelected()){
            System.out.println("Selected");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

If we manage to break out of the loop, "Done" should be printed.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a while loop? `while(!trueButton.isSelected() && !falseButton.isSelected()) {} System.out.print("Selected");` Also, if you're using Swing, this  will basically destroy your GUI.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other difference? Because this make no sense

Comment: A situation of this kind should use listeners on the buttons, and act according to the presses.

Comment: @PaoloForgia yes. That was the only difference. I can't figure out why the first code does not work too.

Comment: To solve this mystery I would suggest to post an [MCVE] including the radio button.

Comment: @c0der noted with thanks. I shall edit the post.

Comment: @Compass thanks for the advice. I tried using the while loop, but it does not work too unless i add System.out.println() within the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

When writing a GUI, you should avoid blocking loops at all costs as it causes your app to be non-responsive.

You should add an ActionListener to "react" to when a button is clicked. Otherwise, you simply check which button is clicked with the `isSelected` method without a loop; for example, when submitting a form or performing some calculation.

If you absolutely need to constantly read the state of a button, use a [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Comment: Thanks. I shall try using ActionListener instead. Do you know the reason why my code does not work?

Comment: Most likely because you have a seemingly infinite loop that has a race condition with the GUI thread. Adding a print statement pauses the code long enough for the condition to pass

Comment: That explanation helps a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  for(;;){            
            if (trueButton.isSelected() || falseButton.isSelected()){
            System.out.print("Selected");
            return;
        }
    }
```

or this:

```
outerloop:
  for(;;){            
            if (trueButton.isSelected() || falseButton.isSelected()){
            System.out.print("Selected");
            break outerloop;
        }
    }
```

otherwise looks like everything is setup right...
hope this helps

Comment: I faced the same problem when I tried the code. It does not work. But I managed to break out of the loop if i add the System.out.println("") statement before the loop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: let me try and replicate your code and see whats going on

Comment: alright. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yea i think the only way is to use a while loop as previously suggested. Or perhaps add an extra pair of brackets to enclose the for loop on the outside . Idk, good luck tho

Comment: Okay. Thanks your time and effort. You might want to take a look at cricket_007 explanation in the comment box for his answer.